# In PhpStorm output section is not showing output in debug window while debugging a connection for Xdebug listen for incomming connection?

Tags: debugging, output, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, is-empty

Here I run command echo "Hi";

[image]

Some days age it was running fine but now... it's showing empty on output section. Output is completely blank on output section of debug window in PhpStorm?

Comment: Just a wild guess but is there any chance that the output is still here but not seen? What happens if you mark output with the selection and copy it to the clipboard, will be there anything copied?

Comment: no sir ... just empty..